# Printing on console depend on content from text file

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, txt

I'm new in C#. I have a text file containing:

```
[False False False]
[ True False False]
[ True False False]
```

How can I write a function that print on console something like if the line is "[False False False]" it prints be 0, if the line is [ True False False] it prints 1, so it will be 0 1 1 line by line. I've already read the text file and printed it line by line to console by the function:

```
public static void PrintData()
        {
            using (var readtext = new StreamReader(@"E:\text.txt"))
            {
                while (!readtext.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\text.txt");

                    foreach (string line in lines)
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (line.IndexOf("True") > 0) Console.WriteLine("1");`

Comment: `StreamReader(@"E:\text.txt")` will open the file, then `File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\text.txt")` will open the file again. You shouldn't do that, use [`readtect.Readline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in essence you are only looking for the string "True"?
you can simply do this:

```
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("True")
    {
       Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `Console.WriteLine(line.Contains(line) ? 1 : 0);` instead of `if`